# Is it possible to run multiple Spark Structured Streaming jobs that write to S3 in parallel?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-emr, spark-structured-streaming

I am trying to run multiple Spark Structured Streaming jobs (on EMR) that read from Kafka topics and write to different paths in S3 (each performed within their respective jobs). I have configured my cluster to use the [CapacityScheduler](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.10.0/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/CapacityScheduler.html). Here is a snippet of the code that I am trying to run:

```
df = spark \
    .readStream \
    .format("kafka") \
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", <BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS>) \
    .option("subscribePattern", "<MY_TOPIC>") \
    .load() \
    .selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)")

output = df \
    .writeStream \
    .format("json") \
    .outputMode("update") \
    .option("checkpointLocation", "s3://<CHECKPOINT_LOCATION>") \
    .option("path", "s3://<SINK>") \
    .start() \
    .awaitTermination()
```

I tried running two jobs in parallel:

```
spark-submit --queue <QUEUE_1> --deploy-mode cluster --master yarn <STREAM_1_SCRIPT>.py
```

```
spark-submit --queue <QUEUE_2> --deploy-mode cluster --master yarn <STREAM_2_SCRIPT>.py
```

During execution, I noticed that the second job was not writing to S3 (even though the first job was). I also noticed a huge spike in the utilization via the Spark UI for the second job.

After stopping the first job, the data showed up for the second job in S3. Is it **not** possible to run two separate Spark Structured Streaming jobs that write to sinks (specifically on S3) in parallel? Does the write operation cause a some kind of blocking?

Comment: What is difference between <STREAM_1_SCRIPT>.py and <STREAM_2_SCRIPT>.py ?

Comment: Is both are using same checkpointLocation ??

Comment: is both are writing to same s3 location ?

Comment: <STREAM_1_SCRIPT>.py and <STREAM_2_SCRIPT>.py contain the snippet of code above. The only difference is in the actual topic names, checkpoint locations, and S3 paths (sink). They are not using the same checkpoint locations.

Comment: instead of multiple parallel task.. you can use multiple topic for read & extract data based on topic name & write that into s3

Comment: I want to have separate jobs so that I can decouple the ingestion of topics from one another. If something happens (such as an error) to one topic I don’t want to have to stop the ingestion of another topic (which would occur because the streams are in a single steaming job).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can !
That's it's not something that had multiple sources docummented but, the only thing that you need its share the spark context between your threads of multiple jobs.
I make a multiple spark structtured streaming pipeline following this article https://cm.engineering/multiple-spark-streaming-jobs-in-a-single-emr-cluster-ca86c28d1411 any questions you can send me an email or talk inbox to me.

Thank you !

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)